# what is the syntax of jobs.deny?

Tags: cron, anacron

from [man](https://linux.die.net/man/4/crontabs) it said

> The execution of files can be allowed or denied by creating file jobs.allow or jobs.deny which worked similar as other allow/deny config files

But the example has something like `0logwatch`, what is the `0` means here? where can I find the exact man page of the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The entries in `jobs.allow` and `jobs.deny` are the file names of cron jobs, as defined in for example `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.daily` etc. A given `jobs.deny` denies the named jobs in the same directory; thus, a `0logwatch` entry in `/etc/cron.daily/jobs.deny` will prevent `/etc/cron.daily/0logwatch` from running.

This isn’t supported by all versions of `cron`; notably, `cron` on Debian derivatives doesn’t support this feature, whereas `cron` on Fedora derivatives do. If you’re using a Fedora derivative, run `man crontabs` there to get an up-to-date man page which is easier to understand than the version you found on the Internet.